# How to run while controller a number of times until i get a result code

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, do-while, status

I have the following doubt:

I need to run my test i.e. HTTP sampler until i get a status code >11 and the maximum number of times I  need to run while loop is 20. As soon as i get a status code > 11 the loop should end. How do I achieve that.

my while loop has condition
:

```
${__javaScript(${Status_Code}<"11" && ${Status_Code}!="11",)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) in order to define the maximum number of iterations for the While Controller
2. Since JMeter 3.1 you should be preferring [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as [Groovy performance is much better than other languages](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Assuming above 2 points I would suggest refactoring your While Controller's condition to be:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int) < 20 && (vars.get('Status_Code')  as int) < 11 ,)}
```

Comment: 1)I am not sure as to where this variable will be defined in my jmeter test, will it be under user defined variable?  2)   Also my condition is Status_Code<11 and Status_Code!=11, how do i write that in Groovy (i dont have much knowledge on groovy)

Comment: looking forward to my above query's response. TIA